# How do I cancel a monthly recurring charge after the first 30 days have been filled?

Tags: php, mysql, stripe-payments

I am using stripe to create a subscription plan, and everything is going smoothly but I would like to create a cancel subscription button, I have looked through stackoverflow for the answer but I am unable to find any help, any helpful resources or code is greatly appreciated!

premium.php:

```
<?php
require_once 'app/init.php';
include 'app/dbh.inc.php';
?>
<html>
<body>
    <p>You're about to go premium.</p>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Premium</title>
      </head>
      <body>
    <form action="premium_charge.php" method="POST">
      <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"
        class="stripe-button"
        data-key="<?php echo $stripe['publishable']; ?>"
        data-name="Connect Kitty"
        data-description="Catwalk"
        data-email="<?php echo $user->email; ?>"
        data-amount="599"
        data-currency="usd">
      </script>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

premium_charge.php:

```
<?php

 require_once 'app/init.php';

if(isset($_POST['stripeToken'])) {

   $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

   try {

      Stripe_Charge::create([
      "amount" => 599,
      "currency" => "usd",
      "source" => $token,
      "description" => $user->email
      ]);
      $db->query("
        UPDATE tbl_twitter_user SET premium = 1
        WHERE user_id = {$user->user_id}
      ");

   } catch(Stripe_CardError $e) {

   }
   header('Location: index1.php');
   exit();
}
?>
```

init.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$stripe = [
   'publishable' => 'pk_test_QR1JpboiLh5acjEhK6vwclar00N1Y0Evjd',
   'private' => 'sk_test_N62K1YeWqBN1WyEsWmK149Rh00It8OTxqg'
];

Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['private']);

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=am', 'nt', 'f9');

$userQuery = $db->prepare("
   SELECT user_id, username, email, premium
   FROM tbl_twitter_user
   WHERE username = :username
");

$userQuery->execute(['username' => $_SESSION['username']]);

$user = $userQuery->fetchObject();
?>
```

I have included all of the code because I am not sure which file I will need to be working with.

And ty if anyone is concerned about SQL Injections!

Comment: [Stripe API Documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/cancel)

Comment: `premium_charge.php` is doing a one-time charge, not creating a subscription.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the subscription, you should save the subscription ID in your database. When the user asks to cancel the subscription, get their subscription ID from the database and call the Stripe API:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT subscription_id FROM tbl_twitter_user WHERE user_id = :userid");
$stmt->execute(['user_id' => $user->user_id]);
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$sub = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($row->subscription_id);
$sub->cancel();
```

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used their buttons. I use stripe.js just for getting the credit card number, we use the PHP API for everything else.

Comment: I have added your code in but I am receiving a red X in doing so. Here is where I placed it after: `WHERE user_id = {$user->user_id}
      "); ` and on the second stmt line, I receive a red X

Comment: I had some typos in my question where I was getting the session variable. Try it now, I changed to using `$user->user_id`.

Comment: Where should put the code sir? We are getting errors where we add it.

Comment: The code goes in the script that you run when they click on your cancel button.

Comment: We do not have a cancel button, where should we put the cancel button? Should we put the cancel button after the line of code that says you are premium?

Comment: Put it anywhere you want. There's nothing special about that. Are you sure you're creating a subscription in the first place? The button you show is just making a charge.

Comment: Instead of subscription_id, wouldn't it be premium, or user_id?

Comment: No, you need to use the subscription ID to retrieve the subscription object from Stripe.

Comment: Where is your code that uses `\Stripe\Subscription::create()`?

Comment: Yes sir, it is a subscription, and it has been set up as a subscription also in stripe.

Comment: Are you using something like this: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/subscriptions

Comment: I don't use Stripe Checkout, I just use Stripe Elements and the API, so I'm not familiar with how you do things with Checkout.

Comment: Have you tried asking Stripe Tech Support? I've always found them very helpful. Why ask here when you're paying them?

Comment: We asked the wrong question, sorry for wasting your time on this. We are making a recurring charge that appears monthly, but we want to cancel it after the user clicks cancel, once they have filled the 30 days, they're recurring charge will no longer affect them. Do you know anyway to achieve this?

Comment: We are currently using an un-activated account on stripe.

Comment: Recurring payments and subscriptions are the same thing on Stripe.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no built-in part of Stripe Checkout for cancelling subscriptions. When the user creates the subscription, there's a webhook that should contain the subscription ID, you'll need to write your own code like my answer to cancel it.

Comment: First of all thank you so much for telling me that I was just charging the card Mr. Barmar I totally missed that. I finally was able to make the whole payment plan a subscription and I now have the \Stripe\Subscription::create() now I need to know how I can save my subscription_id into my database. So i can cancel the subscription.

Comment: Assign the result of `create()` to a variable, e.g. `$sub = \Stripe\Subscription::create([params]);'` Then you can use `$sub->id` to get the subscription ID to save.

Comment: `$sub = \Stripe\Subscription::create([
        "customer" => $customer->id,
        "items" => [
            [
                "plan" => $products[$pid],
            ],
        ]
    ]);` Is this the correct way to do it sir?

Comment: It looks about right, I haven't studied that part of the API carefully. We don't use Stripe subscriptions in our product.

Comment: Where do you recommend we would put `$sub->id`?

Comment: In my answer, it assumes there's a `subscription_id` column in `tbl_twitter_user`.

Comment: Yes, we changed the table name from tbl_twitter_user to users, and we added the column `subscription_id`

Comment: We were able to save the subscription_id in the database, but we need some more help on canceling it.

Comment: I think you should be able to search for the subscription ID in the dashboard, and it should show you the status.

Comment: The status still says active.

Comment: Check the log to see what they're receiving.

Comment: Stripe has a nice log viewer, use it to see what messages they're receiving from your application. I really can't hold your hand through this whole process, you need to learn how to debug on your own.

Comment: The cancel button is not working at all. I had to manually cancel it for it to say canceled, this is the code I have for the cancel button.                                                     
`if(isset($_POST['cancel'])) {
            $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT subscription_id FROM users WHERE id = :id");
            $stmt->execute(['customer' => $customer->id]);
            $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $sub = \Stripe\Subscription::retrieve($row->subscription_id);
            $sub->cancel();
}
`

Comment: `'customer' => $customer->id` should be `'id' => $customer->id`

Comment: I tried this line of code, and it is still not working and I even tried to change $customer to $sub and it is still not working `'id' => $customer->id`

Comment: Without knowing everything that's going on in your application, I can't debug a couple of lines like this. How can you be operating a commercial service without someone who knows how to debug PHP scripts?

Comment: I'm just using the lines of code for a cancel button and the subscription id saves into a database, I didn't know it would be this difficult to achieve this I have looked on youtube for videos for how to cancel a subscription, but all of them are using django, I can not find a single one that is using php, but if you know any videos I would be greatly appreciative.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any videos; I've been programming for 40 years, I don't need that kind of spoon feeding. Have you had any luck checking the Stripe logs in the portal?

Comment: Click on "Developers" in the sidebar, it will expand, then click on "Logs".

Comment: This is what our log looks like: http://worldsunworld.com/Screenshot%202019-09-05%20at%208.15.08%20PM.png

Comment: OK, so find the log messages at the time that you were doing your test, or put the subscriber ID in the Search field?

Comment: I think we have to put an end to this. I'm not your personal Stripe Tech Support person. Maybe it's time for you to pay for a real account there so you can take advantage of their services.